# azure App registration using powershell does not create a service principal

Tags: azure, powershell, azure-active-directory

when we create an azure ad app registration from the azure portal  the service principal is automatically created, and given a contributors role, how do we achieve the same using PowerShell ?

I tried running the following the command the app is created but no service principal is created, and there are no  parameters for configuring a service principle

```
New-AzADApplication -DisplayName "NewApplication" -HomePage "http://www.microsoft.com" -IdentifierUris "http://NewApplication"
```

what i am looking for is to create the following using powershell, is this possible ?

1. AzureADAppregistration + ServicePrincipal
2. Create and get the client secret

Thanks

Comment: You need to use `New-AzureADServicePrincipal` to create the SP

Comment: How's going? Has your issue got resolved? Let me know if you have any questions

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this:

```
#set your secret here.    
$secretTextValue = "abcdefg1234567890" 

$secret = ConvertTo-SecureString -String $secretTextValue -AsPlainText

$app = New-AzADApplication -DisplayName "NewApplication" -HomePage "http://www.microsoft.com" -IdentifierUris "http://NewApplication" 

New-AzADAppCredential -ObjectId $app.ObjectId -Password $secret -EndDate (Get-Date).AddMonths(6)
    
#azure will assign contributor role of current subscription to this SP
New-AzADServicePrincipal -ApplicationId $app.ApplicationId
```

Result:

[image]

[image]

[image]